# Misuse of triangle inequality?

Tags: summation, normed-spaces, expected-value

## Problem

When doing proofs in my statistical learning theory course, I found that professor provided the following reasoning
$$
\mathbb{E}_\sigma[\Vert\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\mathbf{x}_i\Vert_2]\leq 
\sqrt{\mathbb{E}_\sigma[\sum_{i=1}^n\Vert\sigma_i\mathbf{x}_i\Vert_2^2]}
$$
where $\sigma_i$ is Rademacher random variable, i.e. $\Pr[\sigma_i=1]=\Pr[\sigma_i=-1]=\frac{1}{2}$.

This does not seem to be correct to me since if I take the most simple case, where $n=2$, I have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{LHS}&=\mathbb{E}_\sigma[\sqrt{\Vert \mathbf{x}_1\Vert_2^2+\Vert \mathbf{x}_2\Vert_2^2+2\sigma_1\sigma_2\mathbf{x}_1^T\mathbf{x}_2}]\\
\text{RHS}&=\sqrt{\Vert \mathbf{x}_1\Vert_2^2+\Vert \mathbf{x}_2\Vert_2^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
and I may not have any conclusive answer from them.

However, this step is **pivotal** in deriving meaningful generalization bound, so I think I miss something.

Could someone help me? Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E\sqrt Y \leq \sqrt {EY}$ and $E\sigma_i \sigma_j =0$ for $i \neq j$ (assuming indepenedence). So your professor is right.

Comment: Thank you. But I still do not quite understand. Could you provide more details, especially how to deal with summation.

Comment: In the case $n=2$ LHS $\leq \sqrt {E\|x_1\|^{2}+E\|x_2\|^{2}+E\sigma_1 \sigma_2 x_1^{T}x_2}=\sqrt {E\|x_1\|^{2}+E\|x_2\|^{2}}$ =RHS. Same argument works for any $n$.

Comment: I just realized this reasoning has nothing to do with triangle inequality. It is just arithmetic computation. Now I understand, thank you!